# Unexpected return from fetch() query

Tags: php, pdo

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT 1 FROM mxscript_slayer_licensekeys 
                      WHERE `username` = '$user'");
$result1 = $db->query("SELECT 1 FROM mxscript_slayer_licensekeys 
                       WHERE `hardwareID` = '$id'");

if (($result && $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) > 0) 
    && ($result1 && $result1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) > 0)) {
    echo '1';
    exit;
} else {
    echo '2';
    exit;
}
```

I'm trying to detect if `result` and `result1` exist as rows in my database, and I was wondering what I'm doing wrong, as it's echoing 2, when it should be echoing 1. I've double checked all of the data and posting..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say that the biggest thing you are doing wrong is that you aren't using prepared/parameterized qeuries, leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I could go about fixing that please? Thanks.

Comment: @Chase, Look at Phil's answer.

Comment: I will venture a guess that either `$result` or `$result1` is `false`. It's a good practice to enable exceptions on your database object, i.e. `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`.

Comment: hi Chase.  You need to check your values.  Please echo out `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` and `$result1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you should be using prepared statements and parameter binding. Secondly, I don't understand why you're issuing two queries. Simply combine the two conditions into one `WHERE` clause. For example...

```
// enable error reporting and exception errors in PDO
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$result = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mxscript_slayer_licensekeys WHERE `username` = ? AND `hardwareID` = ?');
$result->bindParam(1, $user);
$result->bindParam(2, $id);
$result->execute();

printf('%d row(s) found for username "%s" and hardwareID %s',
    $result->fetchColumn(), $user, $id);
exit;
```

### Update

Whilst your code isn't particularly efficient or secure, I'm not sure why it doesn't work as expected. Needs more information.

Comment: While that's useful, it doesn't explain why the code doesn't work.

Comment: Typo in your second bind, the comma should be an m.

Comment: But as Jack pointed out in another comment, `array(...) > 0` is true, so it seems like it should work.

Comment: @JohnV Cheers. Speedy typing is prone to inaccuracy :)

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much. It's still not working. This really isn't making much sense. If I remove WHERE and everything after it, it says it returned 1 row, but if I add 'username' = '$user' etc, it doesn't work.. The data has also been like quadruple checked..

Comment: OMG i'm such an idiot. Please just consider this a tutorial on SQLi prevention. Thank you very much again, appreciated!

Comment: I had two user variables defined, one as my post data, and one as my database username. Lol. By the way, am I supposed to replace the '?' in your post? Thanks again <3

Comment: @Chase I had a feeling it might be a user input / data issue, hence the extra reporting added to my answer. And no, they are placeholders. See http://php.net/manual/pdo.prepare.php and the examples on that page

Comment: Btw, you don't need `->bindParam()`; just pass `[$user, $id]` as the argument to `->execute()`.

Comment: @Jack I know, same thing in the end. I just thought this would be more illustrative to the OP